# Error in Keras Lambda layer when wrapped function expects non-float argument

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras, layer

I want to wrap a tensorflow function in a Keras Lambda layer as per the docs. However, my inputs are complex64. Here is a more complete example of the code i am using to replicate this behavior:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda
import tensorflow as tf
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, threshold=3, edgeitems=3)


def layer0(inp):
    z = inp[0] + inp[1]
    num = tf.cast(tf.real(z), tf.complex64)
    return z/num


if __name__ == "__main__":

    shape = (1,10,5)
    z1 = Input(shape=shape[1:], dtype=np.complex64)
    z2 = Input(shape=shape[1:], dtype=np.complex64)

    #s = Lambda(layer0, output_shape=shape)([z1, z2])
    s = Lambda(layer0)([z1, z2])

    model = Model(inputs=[z1,z2], outputs=s)

    z1_in = np.asarray(np.random.normal(size=shape) + np.random.normal(size=shape)*1j, 'complex64')
    z2_in = np.asarray(np.random.normal(size=shape) + np.random.normal(size=shape)*1j, 'complex64')

    s_out = model.predict([z1_in, z2_in])
    print(s_out)
```

which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complex_lambda.py", line 32, in <module>
    s = Lambda(layer0)([z1, z2])
  File "complex_lambda.py", line 18, in layer0
    return z/num
TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.complex64
```

However, if I use the commented line instead: 
`s = Lambda(layer0, output_shape=shape)([z1, z2])`

The code runs just fine. It seems that "output_shape=(...)" is necessary to make the division in the lambda function work. While this solution solves the problem for a single output variable, it doesn't work when having multiple outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue. Which version of `tensorflow` are you using? Are you using the `keras` package, or the `tensorflow.keras` submodule ?

At any rate, I think you can fix your issue by specifying the `dtype` of the `Lambda` layer : `s = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.real(x[0] + x[1]), dtype='complex64')([z1, s2])`

Comment: Sorry for being so unspecific. I am using tensorflow 1.14.0, Keras 2.2.4 and python 3.7.4; Further, I have built a more complete example of this issue:

Comment: @rrbluke No problem, thanks for clarifying. I set up a virtualenv with the same packages (save for keras being 2.2.5), and still cannot replicate your issue; I am able to run your exact code, then `eval` the output based on random complex numpy arrays...